# How to manage rotations in a subclass of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, rotation

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` in a universal application and I have to set different frame for iPhone and iPad and I have to consider the different orientations but can not be recognized  the orientation of the device. `UIDeviceOrientation` is in the wrong place? `UIDeviceOrientation` return `0`.
This is the code in `CustomCell.m`

```
 -(void) layoutCellPortrait{
 if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

         //......frame subviews iPhone

 }else{

      //........frame subviews Ipad

 }

 }
 -(void) layoutCellLandscape{
     if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

         //.....frame subviews iPhone

     }else{

        //.......frame subviews Ipad

 }

}


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
   {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) {

    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation];
    NSLog(@"The orientation is è %d", deviceOrientation);//here return 0

    if(deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || deviceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

         [self layoutCellPortrait];

    }
    else if (deviceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        [self layoutCellLandscape];

    }
    else if (deviceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){

        [self layoutCellLandscape];

    }


    [self.contentView addSubview:self.subviews];

}
return self;
 }
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check it.

Comment: Have you tried to implement -layoutSubviews in your UITableViewCell subclass? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout.html

Answer (score 2):

Implement the rotation delegates in your class and whenever a rotation happens call a method in your cell class with this orientation as an input param(Assuming that you are calling a `reloadData` on the table which in turn calls this method which is in `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method. This should reset the frame accordingly in each rotations.

**Update:**

In rotation delegate,

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
  self.interfaceOrientation = orientation;
}

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

In tabelView `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
   CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
   }
  //code..
  [cell rearrangeSubviewsForOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];

  return cell;
}
```

In your `cell` class add this,

```
- (void)rearrangeSubviewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

        //iPhone
        if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
            //portait
        } else {
            //landscape
        }

    } else {

        //iPad
        if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
            //portait
        } else {
            //landscape
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
 --- your code ----
}
```

1. Each time when device is rotated this method will be called.
2. write code inside the bracket that you want run, when device is rotated

Note: This is for class which is a subclass of UITableViewCell

If you want to detect orientation change in class which is a subclass like UIViewController there is a similar method called **viewDidLayoutSubviews** below

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
 --- your code ---
}
```

Comment: nicely answered. great one

Answer (score 2):

For **Swift**, if you have customs `UIView`s inside your `UITableViewCell` without `AutoLayout` and you want to update the UI at the orientation change, you can do this inside the `UITableViewCell` custom class:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.customView.layoutSubviews()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have done the same thing. First you need to make two UITableViewCell.xib for different orientation then in your viewController implement the below method.

You don't need to detect device orientation in your customCell.xib ViewController Manage tabelView orientation automatically.

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        if(self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        {


        }
        else
        {


        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
[yourTable reloadData];
}
```

**Then in your tabelView CellForRowAtIndexPath Method implement the below Code**

```
if(self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
        {  

            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            CategoryCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[CategoryCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
                cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

            }
}
else{
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";
            CategoryCell1 *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[CategoryCell1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
                cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
                            }
```

Comment: I have a subviews of UITableViewCell to put into a different position depending on the orientation, you can not do everything inside the subclass of UITableViewCell? How do I in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**?

Comment: My mean is that you don't need to implement the logic for orientation on uitableViewCell. Just where (on ViewController) you are loading your customCells it may be UITableViewController or UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

2 things you need to take a look are:

1. First, check if device did rotate to reload your table using

   -(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
     [self.tableView reloadData];
   }
2. Second, in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, use UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation) to check GUI state to load layout that you want.